# Add distinct id with Key and Values in React Select multi from a csv headers

Tags: reactjs, csv, react-select

When i upload a csv file, i segregated headers and rows for future use. I want to display all the headers of that csv using react-select where user can select which header they want to keep and which is not.

I have successfully added the header names into state variable but unable to render the values inside react select. I want to add distinct id along with values and names parameters as a dict object and select and unselect the header names.

I am attaching coding sandbox for a clearer idea [Load csv header into react select](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-csv-wk2sp5?file=/src/App.js)

Currently the implementation is looking like same as the attached image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has many issues.

- I will declare a `value` state to represent the selected option.
- Don't create the `fileReader` instance in React component function. Every time the component renders, a new `fileReader` instance will be created which is unnecessary.
- Transform the CSV data to select options, the data structure can be `{ label: string; value: string; }[]`
- When the `onChange` event is triggered, call `setValue()` instead of `setOptions()` set the selected options.
- Set the selected options in the `csvFileToArray()` function by calling `setValue()`.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

function App() {
    const [file, setFile] = useState();
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
    const [value, setValue] = useState();

    const handleOnChange = (e) => {
        setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    };

    const csvFileToArray = (csvString) => {
        const csvHeader = csvString.slice(0, csvString.indexOf('\n')).split(',');
        const arr = csvHeader.map((item) => ({
            value: item,
            label: item,
        }));
        console.log(arr);
        setValue(arr);
        setOptions(arr);
    };

    const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (file) {
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function (event) {
                const text = event.target.result;
                csvFileToArray(text);
            };
            fileReader.readAsText(file);
        }
    };

    const onhandleSelect = (data) => {
        setValue(data);
    };

    return (
        <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
            <h1>LOAD CSV DATA INTO REACT SELECT</h1>
            <form>
                <input type={'file'} id={'csvFileInput'} accept={'.csv'} onChange={handleOnChange} />
                <button
                    onClick={(e) => {
                        handleOnSubmit(e);
                    }}>
                    IMPORT CSV
                </button>
            </form>
            <Select
                className="react-select-container"
                classNamePrefix="react-select"
                isMulti
                name="form-field-name"
                value={value}
                onChange={onhandleSelect}
                options={options}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

An example CSV file for testing.

`addresses.csv`:

```
John,Doe,120 jefferson st.,Riverside, NJ, 08075
Jack,McGinnis,220 hobo Av.,Phila, PA,09119
"John ""Da Man""",Repici,120 Jefferson St.,Riverside, NJ,08075
Stephen,Tyler,"7452 Terrace ""At the Plaza"" road",SomeTown,SD, 91234
,Blankman,,SomeTown, SD, 00298
"Joan ""the bone"", Anne",Jet,"9th, at Terrace plc",Desert City,CO,00123
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76799940-9cntyh)

Comment: Thank you for your kind cooperation. I was looking foe the exact thing.